# Maven Build error :Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config

Tags: maven

I am using `Redhat6` ,`java1.6_45` ,`maven2.2.1`
I don't know what is wrong with maven.
When I do `mvn install` I get

`Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1`

How do I solve this problem.?

This is my POM

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.varun.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>sampleproject</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>sampleproject Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring ORM support -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring Batch -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
   <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0.CR2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0.CR2</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>antlr</groupId>
   <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
   <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>stax</groupId>
   <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.12</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-activation_1.1_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
     <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
     <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
     <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
   <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.12</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
   <artifactId>wstx-asl</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
   <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
   <version>4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.javaetmoi.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaetmoi-spring4-vfs2-support</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
 
 
 <!--edited replace cn.guoyukun.jdbc with com.oracle -->
 <!--edited replace oracle-ojdbc6 with ojdbc6 and version 11.2.0.3.0 with 11.2.0.3 -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
 -->
 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
   <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.batch-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
   <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
   <version>1.6</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>copy-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
       <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
       <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <resources>
  <!--
   <resource>
    <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   -->
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/java/com/sampleproject/varun/project/model/</directory>
    <targetPath>com/sampleproject/varun/project/model/</targetPath>
    <includes>
     <include>*.hbm.xml</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>

 </build>
</project>
```

When I go to .M2 folder I am able to trace `org.apache` but there no folder called genesis.
I am new to maven dont have much knowledge about maven.
What is the cause of this problem.

**Updated: 1** 
I tried to clean my maven cache manually and command both way. 
1st way : I deleted the all the content of repository, and run the command
`mvn -install clean -e`.
Log file after running the command

```html
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sampleproject Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/qaserver3/.jenkins/jobs/sampleproject/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/qaserver3/.jenkins/jobs/sampleproject/src/main/java/com/varun/myproject/model
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: null:project-config:pom:1.1

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
  org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
 1) com.varun.batch:sampleproject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 2) org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.6.1
 3) org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.6.1
 4) org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.12


 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:711)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
  org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Path to dependency: 
 1) com.varun.batch:sampleproject:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 2) org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-local:jar:1.6.1
 3) org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.6.1
 4) org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.12


 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:430)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:435)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:435)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:435)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:74)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:304)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.resolveTransitiveDependencies(DefaultPluginManager.java:1499)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:442)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataRetrievalException: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
 at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:200)
 at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:94)
 at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:387)
 ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config for project: null:project-config:pom:1.1 for project null:project-config:pom:1.1
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1407)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1407)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
 at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
 ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:config at /home/qaserver3/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config/config/1.1/config-1.1.pom
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1599)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
 ... 33 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 27 05:53:08 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/223M
```

**2nd way :** 
I tried this command also:
`mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

**3rd way:** I downloaded the jar and pasted into `./home/varun/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config`
this also dint work for me.

Please suggest how do I solve this issue?

Update 2: As suggested in second answer I created the `setting.xml` file and paste the content.and deleted the all content of a repository.and ran the command `mvn clean install`.
I checked the `/home/qaserver3/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config/config/1.1/config-1.1.pom` file and now the contents are changed.
there is no more html content in `config-1.1.pom`
content in `config-1.1.pom`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>genesis</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.genesis</groupId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config</groupId>
  <artifactId>config</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Genesis Configuration</name>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <modules>
    <module>logging-config</module>
    <module>checkstyle-config</module>
    <module>project-config</module>
    <module>geronimo-skin</module>
  </modules>
  <distributionManagement>
    <status>deployed</status>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

But now its creating problem in generating .war file.

**LOG:**

```
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'f0fa4a497370d416d82bc679e62bd695f7d24f7a'; remote = '<!DOCTYPE' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.3.4.O/xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
11K downloaded  (plexus-io-1.0-alpha-1.jar)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.2/plexus-interpolation-1.2.jar
35K downloaded  (plexus-interpolation-1.2.jar)
2K downloaded  (xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'f0fa4a497370d416d82bc679e62bd695f7d24f7a'; remote = '<!DOCTYPE' - IGNORING
[INFO] [war:war {execution: default-war}]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp[gsdataprocessor] in [/home/varun/.jenkins/jobs/sampleproject/target/gsdataprocessor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in[103 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/varun/.jenkins/jobs/sampleproject/target/sampleproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4 minutes 33 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 27 23:57:47 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/177M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[qaserver3@qaserver3 gsdataprocessor]$
```

Sorry could not post complete log. question Body has limitation.

Comment: Can you public your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: @Valijon you want me to post my pom in question ?

Comment: By the way, did you try: [https://github.com/GCRC/nunaliit/issues/329](https://github.com/GCRC/nunaliit/issues/329)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do i wiped out my maven catch??

Comment: manually. What is your Operating System? WIndows/Unix?

Comment: I see. go to your home path ($HOME) and navigate in ./.m2/repository/... The jar is in package path... org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config/...

Answer (score 2):

The POM with the coordinates `org.apache.geronimo.genesis.config:project-config:1.1` references the Codehaus repository. This repository has been discontinued.

Unfortunately, there are a few POMs out there that reference this repository and they are set in stone. What you need to do is to bypass this repository and tell Maven to use the central repo instead.

If you haven't got one already, create a file called `~/.m2/settings.xml` (or in the user's directory that is executing Maven) and add this content:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0                                                                                                                   
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
     <id>codehaus-bypass</id>
     <name>Codehaus bypass mirror</name>
     <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
     <mirrorOf>codehaus</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Next, delete the directory `<your local repo>/org/apache/geronimo/genesis/config`.

Rerun Maven.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Daniel.. please see the update in question

Comment: Yes, your project is lacking a `web.xml` file and Maven is searching by default in the directory`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` for it.

Comment: Bro it worked. I changed the maven 2.2.1 version to 3.0.5. and changed to root user. and it works fine. Thanks for your support. if u changed the ans I will accept it. maven was installed as a normal user.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear it's working out for you. You can get permission problems if the repo has been touched by two different users, since the directories might have different ownerships. I guess running as root will fix the problem in the short-term, but the proper way of doing it is to scratch the repo and make sure only one user (typically Jenkins) accesses the repo.

Answer (score 1):

`geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec` is a dependency of `axiom-api`, but it's only required on Java 5. Since you are using Java 6, you can simply exclude that dependency. There is no need to make your build unreproducible by adding configuration to `settings.xml` or by deploying files manually to the Maven repository.